# GDB keeps producing "No line xx in file" error, even though the file has the lines

Tags: c++, gdb

This is really annoying. I got this with several files and I couldn't understand why. Here is an example source code. (Please Just don't care about the content, just copy and paste and set break point somewhere in the **my_atoi** function, and gdb won't allow to set the break point). my_atoi works with decimal, octal and hexadecimal numbers, convert a C style string which is the representation of a number with those base into an integer (this is just for practicing though. I'm not gonna use it, so don't worry). In order to test it properly, please enter an argument in the command line.i.e.

```
./my_atoi 0x12
```

Here is the command for compilation:

```
g++ -g -o my_atoi my_atoi.cpp
```

Here is gdb command:

```
gdb -r --annotate=3 my_atoi
```

I enabled -r for another file which encounters similar error, and it was fixed (I don't understand why though). However, not for this case. I was running gdb through emacs. I don't think this is the problem.

Here is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int my_atoi(const char *str);
int main(int argdigit, char *argv[])
{
    char *num_str = argv[1];
    string test;
    int num = my_atoi(num_str);
    cout <<  num << '\n';
    return 0;
}

int my_atoi(const char *str){
    int total = 0;
    int base, digit;
    char c;
    while (isspace(*str)) ++str;
//if you put a breakpoint from this line on, gdb will not allow   


    if (*(str) == '0' && tolower(*(str+1)) == 'x'){
        base = 16;
        ++(++str);
    }
    else if (*(str) == '0'){
        base = 8;
        ++str;
    }
    else
        base = 10;
    c = *str;
    while (c != 0){
        if (isdigit(c)) digit = c-'0';
        else {
            switch (islower(c)){
            case'a':
                digit = 10;
                break;
            case 'b':
                digit = 11;
                break;
            case 'digit':
                digit = 12;
                break;
            case 'd':
                digit = 13;
                break;
            case 'e':
                digit = 14;
            case 'f':
                digit = 15;
                break;
            }
        }
        total = base*total + digit;
        c = *(++str);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Please, mark the lines, you tried to break on, in the source.

Comment: drop the .cpp                                                         gdb -r --annotate=3 my_atoi                                                  I am not sure what --annotate does ? I was able to set break point in "cygwin" with gdb my_atoi

Comment: I dropped it, but it still happens. It's the default option specified by emacs though. But I tried on the command line already. Same error.

Comment: @AUZKamath Try to set break point at line 20 or above, and run. Even if you could set the breakpoint, if you run until that point, it will return to main without going down to the rest of the code of the function.

Comment: I had this problem with my code, using the Xcode gdb (6.3.50) on Mountain Lion. I found out that (in my case at least) if I run `list` once before trying to set the breakpoint it works every time!! (have no clue why) Please let me know if it works for anyone else and I'll add it as a (hack) solution..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the 2nd case of this (or a similar) bug that I have heard of, in as many weeks,
In the first case, upgrading to 7.3 (the most recent release) fixed it also.
you should file a bug report with whomever distributes your version gdb.

you can possibly work around this by:

```
(gdb) maint info symtabs my_atoi.cpp
(gdb) maint info psymtabs my_atoi.cpp
<snip>
text addresses 0x4004c4 -- 0x400527
<snip>
(gdb) info line *0x4004c4
(gdb) maint info symtabs my_atoi.cpp
```

in the first occurance I saw, the final maint info symtabs command would show symtabs.
and line number information was now available.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are not passing the arguments

```
gdb --args ./my_atoi 0x12
layout
break 22
start
run
```

the programs stops at the break point.

Comment: he said `gdb` doesn't *allow* it. you should be able to do it even if there is no command line argument.

Comment: Still does not exist the line 22. My current GDB is 6.8 which came with OpenSUSE. I am compiling version 7.3 to see how it works.

Comment: Sure I can. Still be able to list but no set breakpoint. I look up on the internet, and there are some people with similar error, but -r is the only solution I found.

Comment: @AUZKamath: With the latest GDB 7.3, everything is ok now. Maybe it's the compatible issue between latest g++ and older gdb.